# CDN server issue -Font from origin has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy on Asp.net Platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, web-config, cdn

I am implementing CDN Server links in my website, while implementing font files are not working on my website pages, i m getting error in browser console.PF screenshot for your reference. My website platform is Asp.net.

I tried below code in web.config 
 `<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>`

[image]